# UIBarButtonItem Vertical Positioning

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

How do I set the vertical position of a UIBarButtonItem? I can set the horizontal positioning without much effort, but the vertical position has me stumped. Thanks!

```
UIBarButtonItem *leftBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(link:)];
UIBarButtonItem *leftSpacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
[leftSpacer setWidth:10];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:leftSpacer,leftBarItem,nil];
```

Comment: use custom button as barButtonItem.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to change the canvas size of the image you are using and then adjust it to where you want within your image.